# Best character assignment method in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Running into a problem with the following example code for which I hope there is a way around.

Say I have defined a function:

```
f[x_,y_,z_] = x + y + z + x Log[x] + y Log[y] +z Log[z]
```

and I was to assign

```
f[x_,y_,z_] = x + y + z + x Log[x] + y Log[y] +z Log[z]//.x->1//.y->1//.z->0
```

But rather than have Mathematica replace z with 0 I just want z to be ignored to give the result `f[x_,y_] = 2` without having to define a new function. Entering the above code into Mathematica results in an obvious `Indeterminate` solution

Helping this novice out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about a simple If statement in the function to check on the argument in question, like we used to do in the good old days :), based on the result of the IF statement you do one thing vs. the other.

It also makes the logic more clear and more portable. Any way, that is how I would do it.

Comment: @Nasser If you don't define the third argument as optional, the 3 args function will not run with 2 args

Comment: @Belisarius, may be I was not clear. I meant, leave it as original 3 argument function, and inside that function, add a logic to check for the offending value(s) to avoid. i.e. If z==0, do not do the log(). If there is 1/z, do not do that computation, and so on. All the logic is now in one place, instead of spread among few functions, each designed to handle one special case.

Comment: @ZB18749 Note that in this case `ReplaceRepeated` (//.) doesn't seem to make more sense than `ReplaceAll` (/.). Also, you might want to gather all replacement rules together in one replacement `/. {x->1,y->1,z->0` which usually yields the same result and is shorter. There are exceptions, where order is important like in `x Log[y] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}` which yields an error whereas `x Log[y] /. {x -> 0} /. {y -> 0}` yields 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want the treatment you describe for `z` to apply to `x` and `y` as well, you could do this:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := g[x] + g[y] + g[z]

g[0] = 0;
g[x_] := x + x Log[x]
```

The helper function `g` handles the zero case explicitly.  These definitions yield results like these:

```
f[1, E, E^2]
(* 1 + 2*E + 3*E^2 *)

f[1, 1, 1]
(* 3 *)

f[1, 1, 0]
(* 2 *)

f[0, 0, E]
(* 2*E *)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, function application occurs by calling the function:

```
f[1,1,1]
```

Second, why not introduce a new function using limit?

```
f[x_,y_,z_] := x + y + z + x*Log[x] + y*Log[y] +z*Log[z]
g[x_,y_]:=Limit[f[x,y,z],z->0]
g[1,1]
```

That should give you the `2`, though I'm not in front of mathematica now so i havent checked

Comment: You don't need a new name for the fuction. `f[x_, y_] := Limit[f[x, y, z], z -> 0]` will also work when used as f[1,1]. Mathematica pattern matching engine will take control to use the correct definition